# JavaME-suitable grammar compiler recommendations?

Tags: java, parsing, java-me, grammar, bnf

I want to parse some data, and I have a BNF grammar to parse it with. Can anyone recommend any grammar compilers capable of generating code that can be used on a mobile device?

Since this is for JavaME, the generated code must be:

- Hopefully pretty small
- Low dependencies on exotic Java libraries
- Not dependant on any runtime jar files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [JFlex](http://jflex.de/) before, and I know it satisfies your second and third requirements. But I don't know how big the generated code might be. According to the [manual](http://jflex.de/manual.html#CodeGeneration), it generates a packed DFA table by default, so it might not be too bad.

Answer (score 1):

The first question is do you have an existing grammar definition?  When I've ported a LALR grammar to Java, I've used JFlex/CUP.

If your starting from scratch, I'd suggest you use JavaCC/FreeCC, which is an LL(k) parser.  It's quite well documented and there are not runtime dependencies.